# Is there a way to edit the title of live support chat in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I am currently doing up a site page in Odoo. One of my objective is to edit the title of the Live Support chat box from "Have a Question?Chat with Us" to "Welcome, feel free to chat with us if you have any queries". Does anyone know where I should actually edit?

P.s: I can't upload any pic since I do not have high enough of reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the **Text of the button** field value.

[image]

[image]